# How to waterproof electronics for an underwater project?

Tags: sensor, waterproof, underwater

I am building a project that has to do with underwater and I am having trouble waterproofing the electronic and the depth is about 15-20 feet. How will I assure that the electronic will be waterproof at that depth. Thank you

Comment: More info required. A bare board vs sealed box vs box with holes for cables and sensor vs a submarine with holes for moving part are all quite different. Time matters too.

Comment: Epoxy can waterproof it.

Answer (score 1):

15-20 ft underwater is a about 7 - 10 psi (0.5 - 0.7 atm). A sealed polycarbonate box thick enough to withstand that pressure should do the trick. If you need cables to/from the electronics that’s a bit more work.

You can also consider filling the enclosure with a nonconducting, incompressible fluid such as oil. That’s what they do with stuff that has to go really deep (think ROVs like they use on oil rigs.) Of course your components cannot have any air voids, and they have to be compatible with the fluid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not intending to keep it running for a long time all you need to do is put the circuit board in a box and fill it with paraffin wax

Comment: I think this answer is premature since the OP has not provided information on the size of his project, how much power will need to be dissipated, how long it will be submerged, cables and any other items that need to project from his device, how accessible does the device need to be after waterproofing, how many times will it be submerged and then brought to the surface, etc.

Comment: @Barry The only real worry might be power dissipation. Apart from that another potting compound would be standard practice